# Error: Full component analysis cannot be performed until the Pom is valid

Tags: maven, servlets, pom.xml

I am currently working on Java Servlet project on VSCode, using Tomcat Server 9.x, Apache Maven 3.9.5.  I have this extension installed named "Red Hat Dependency Analytics".

Whenever I open the pom.xml file of my project or makes any changes in it, the extension gives the error "Full component analysis cannot be performed until the Pom is valid.".

On MAVEN INSTALL command there are no errors, then Why I am getting this error?

[maven install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lpip.png) [maven verify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKnPh.png)

pom.xml:

```
<!-- Maven Project Object Model (POM) -> Configures project and its dependencies. -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>TEST</groupId>
  <artifactId>TEST</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.11.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: First remove `<finalName>` also use most recent versions of plugins (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) furthermore run your build first on plain command line (not from within your ide)... and see if there are any issues...

Comment: There are no issues on building project,  It builds without any issues. Here is the SS of error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OyIt.png

Comment: Ah good to know that..but that means the problem is related to the VSCode extension... btw. Is you build without any warning on plain console?

Comment: I have no clue how to build it on terminal manually. I'm building .war file from  Maven INSTALL command [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DgbM.png ] , This is what happens on clicking install: [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lpip.png ]

Comment: First I strongly recommend to learn how that works. Just use the commands `mvn verify` on plain console... apart from that the output shows that the build works perfectly find as I already mentioned that seemed to be a problem in the VSCode extension where I can not help because I don't use VSCode for Java...

Comment: Yeah, mvn verify doesnt give any error.

Comment: That makes it now clear that the problem is the extension in VSCode...

Answer (score -1):

Restarting VScode + (Ctrl+S) in the pom.xml file + Run the app from starting java file; solved my similar problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).